# Display images in jsp

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee

I read related topics and didn't understood,i must put images and all static content under root or i can put in any folder?(how i can display image1.jpg?)
p.s. I didn't understood why all images don't display if point in servlet  urlPatterns={"/"}.I found only that urlPatterns={"/"} is bad practise,but why  images are not display ?
Structure folders:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use the fabric driver which has the following [URL scheme](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-utilities/1.5/en/connector-j-fabric-connect.html):

```
jdbc:mysql:fabric://fabrichost:32274/database
```

Alternatively you can use the normal Mysql JDBC driver which is `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`

So either change the URL scheme or the driver class.